Understand the workings of \keys_precompile:nnN
I do not really understand the workings of \keys_precompile:nnN.  Does it run every time \l_kvi_adrs_reset_tl gets called ?
\NewDocumentCommand {\ladrs} { s m }
 {
  \IfBooleanF {#1} { \l_kvi_adrs_reset_tl }
  \kvi_adrs:nn { left } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand {\radrs} { s m }
 {
  \IfBooleanF {#1} { \l_kvi_adrs_reset_tl }
  \kvi_adrs:nn { right } { #2 }
 }

\keys_define:nn { kvi_adrs }
 {
  name .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_name_tl,
  role .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_role_tl,
  kmpn .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_kmpn_tl,
  dwlg .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_dwlg_tl,
  hmlt .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_hmlt_tl,
  vltw .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_wltw_tl,
  cbrg .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_cbrg_tl,
  knty .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_knty_tl,
  pstc .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_pstc_tl,
  ktry .tl_set:N = \l_kvi_adrs_ktry_tl,
}

\tl_new:N \l_kvi_adrs_reset_tl

\keys_precompile:nnN { kvi_adrs }
 {
  name = , role = , kmpn = , dwlg = , hmlt = ,
  vltw = , cbrg = , knty = , pstc = , ktry = ,
 } \l_kvi_adrs_reset_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kvi_adrs:nn
 {
  \keys_set:nn {kvi_adrs} {#2}
  \begin {flush#1} \imprint_adrs: \end {flush#1}
 }



Does it run every time \l_kvi_adrs_reset_tl gets called ?

No it is the definition of that command.
If you execute the key setting
{
  name = , role = , kmpn = , dwlg = , hmlt = ,
  vltw = , cbrg = , knty = , pstc = , ktry = ,
 }

then normally latex has to iterate through the comma list, split on =, trim white space, then execute the code for each key which for name here would be \def\l_kvi_adrs_name_tl{} and similarly the other keys.
If you just execute this once the cost isn't great but you are potentially wanting to do this initialization setting every time so the precompile lets you just do the keyval parse once and save the underlying commands in the specified tl variable. so it is equivalent to essentially
\def\l_kvi_adrs_name_tl{%
    \def\l_kvi_adrs_name_tl{}%
    \def\l_kvi_adrs_role_tl{}%
     ...
}

so when you do
  \IfBooleanF {#1} { \l_kvi_adrs_reset_tl }

then all the internal variables are quicky initialized without having to parse a , = list and construct the assignments.

Basically you are providing {} to the l3keys internals directly.

@Bulldrive well only because the values in the supplied keyval list are empty. You have name = ,  if you had name = xyz. It would have saved \def...{xyz}
